# Is it possible to Install Xcode on MAC 9.6

Tags: xcode

I want to Install any smooth working version of XCODE(for Iphone Apps development) on MAC machine having configuration as follows:-
**MAC OS Z1-9.2.2,
Built In RAM-128 MB,
MAC OS ROM 9.0.1.**

What are the feasibilities with that MAC.
Please help as I am just One day old for MAC.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. It requires a modern Mac OS X. Xcode4 requires at least Snow Leopoard, and IIRC so does the current Xcode 3.2.x.

Even *if* it were possible, my Xcode4 right now occupies about 590MB of RAM at the moment of this writing. You wouldn't want to run something like that on a system with just 128MB RAM.

Comment: If possible Can I Upgrade my RAM to required MBs and Is it possible to upgrade my MAC OS from any APPLe website.

Comment: Still not possible. I've got no idea what machine exactly you've got, but if it's running Mac OS 9.x it must be a PowerPC machine. And Snow Leopoard doesn't support PowerPC any more, only Intel. Even if you would be able to run Mac OS X on your machine, and even if you would be able to cram 2GB of RAM into your machine, your CPU still would be way too slow (and I bet even your harddisk in this machine would be a problem). Buy a cheap used Intel Mac Mini on eBay or if you have the money, an iMac or MacBook Pro.